# GCC warning to identify copying structures that contains pointers

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any GCC warning that cautions when I try to copy structures containing pointers with assignment operator instead of deep copying?

Comment: In recent versions of GCC, you can use `gcc --help=warnings` to get all the warnings listed.

Comment: `-Wall` gives a selection of the most useful warnings; it does not give you _all_ warnings.  Neither does `-Wall -Wextra`; there are esoteric warnings that are not triggered by either of these.

Comment: @EvanLi That's still wrong.

Comment: For what it is worth: to copy a struct with plain assignment should never be done without knowing and considering all members of the struct. Whenever you consider such an assignment, warning bells should appear inside your head, before you even get as far as compiling.

Comment: Thanks to @JonathanLeffler. I learned.

Comment: @EvanLi I didn't learn, because you deleted half of the conversation above.

Comment: @rubenvb I don't want to leave wrong statement there, so I deleted it. But I up-voted Jonathan's comment from which I learned.

Comment: @rubenvb: The gist of the problem is that despite its name, the `-Wall` option does not generate 'all possible warnings' from GCC. It only activates a carefully selected set of warnings, ones which are generally accepted as tolerable to positively beneficial. The list of such warnings does (at least potentially) change from release to release of GCC.  So do the extra warnings enabled by `-Wextra`; they are less widely accepted, for all they're mostly technically correct.  It is also harder to fix code so that it gets no warnings under `-Wextra`.  Then there are the other warnings...

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. See the list of gcc [warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Given the same page, warnings are:

> Warnings are diagnostic messages that report constructions that are not inherently erroneous but that are risky or suggest there may have been an error.

And shallow copy instead of a deep copy is neither risky nor erroneous as it may be an intended behavior. So there is no reason for such warning option to exist.

What you may want is a static analyzer such as [clang's one](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/index.html), though in my knowledge this one doesn't offer that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing precisely such a warning with `-Weffc++`

Of course, you'd have to be willing to compile in c++ mode. (See below)

**Edit** I tested it: Sadly, this won't warn about POD (i.e.) C types. Here is the test:

```
struct HasPointer
{
    int* resource;
    HasPointer() {};
    ~HasPointer() {};
};
```

Compiled with

```
E:\mingw64>g++ test.c -Weffc++
```

Outputs

```
test.c:1:8: warning: 'struct HasPointer' has pointer data members [-Weffc++]
 struct HasPointer
        ^
test.c:1:8: warning:   but does not override 'HasPointer(const HasPointer&)' [-Weffc++]
test.c:1:8: warning:   or 'operator=(const HasPointer&)' [-Weffc++]
test.c: In constructor 'HasPointer::HasPointer()':
```

But leaving the ctor/dtor out, the warning isn't even emitted, **so this option doesn't work for your code, even in C++ compile mode**.

---

Compiling C code in C++ mode:

(Use `extern "C"`) to achieve binary interoperability. It is usually as simple as

```
extern "C" 
{
#    include "my.h"
#    include "stuff.h"

// ... 
}
```